Understanding how to compute expected values
I have two problems that guide my confusion. Recently, I learnt measure theoretic probability, and the setup for defining expected value is as follows: We let $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, \mu)$ be a probability space where $\Omega$ is the underlying set, $\mathcal{F}$ is a $\sigma$-algebra on $\mathcal{P}(X)$ and $\mu : \mathcal{F} \to [0,1]$ is a measure such that $\mu(\Omega) = 1$. Then, a random variable $X : \Omega \to S$ where $S$ is part of the probability space $(S, \mathcal{B}, \nu)$ is simply a measurable function between $(\Omega, \mathcal{F})$ and $(S, \mathcal{B})$. Now $\mathbb{E}X := \int_{\Omega} X d\mu$ where $d\mu$ just means the integral is taken with respect to the measure $\mu$ on $\Omega$.
Now, as a concrete example, I was given the problem to calculate $\mathbb{E}[e^{iX}]$ where $X \sim Unif(-1,1)$, so $X$ is a uniformly distributed random variable. Firstly, what is $X$ a measurable function from? I thought $X$ being uniform meant $X:(-1,1) \to (-1,1)$ was the map $X(x) = x$ and so naively I said $ \int_{-1}^1 e^{ix} dx$, but this is missing a factor of $1/2$, and I just don't see how to get it from the measure theoretic definition.
Similarly, another calculation was that given $Y$ uniformly distributed on the unit ball, calculate $\mathbb{E} \log|Y|$. This time, I believed $Y:B(0,1) \to B(0,1)$ was given by $Y(z) = z$ and once again thought it would be $\int_{B(0,1)} \log |x| dx$, but this is missing a factor of $1/\pi$. I don't really understand how these calculations are done, I can understand how to calculate expected values for discrete distributions as they are defined as $\mathbb{E}X = \sum_{\omega = X(x)} \omega \mathbb{P}(X = \omega)$ and the distribution of $X$ means giving you $\mathbb{P}(X = \omega)$, but how do you, from the distribution, know what the domain and the measurable function is? And where are these factors coming from?

$X, Y$ etc are defined on some probability space, and it doesn't matter what those spaces are.  $Ee^{iX}=\frac1  2 \int_{-1}^{1} e^{it} dt$.

But how did you get that expression from the definition of expected value $\mathbb{E}X = \int_{\Omega} X d\mu$? We are just given this definition for it in our textbook?

It is a "change of variable formula". Books on Probability will surely mention this.

The comments above are good. Another way is to simply note that the notation $\int_{\Omega} Xd\mu$ for $E[X]$ is measure-theoretic notation for "integration with respect to a probability measure." The easiest way to convert that into a standard integral you would see in calculus is when you have a PDF, it converts to $E[X]=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}x f_X(x)dx$. The measure-theory version is close to the following: For "small" $\delta>0$ and "large" $n>0$ (large enough for $n\delta$ to be large, say, $n\geq 1/\delta^2$), consider $E[X]\approx\sum_{i=-n}^n (i\delta)P[X \in ((i-1)\delta, i\delta]]$.

If you define $\nu(A)=\mu(\{\omega\in \Omega:X(\omega)\in A\})=\mu(X^{-1}(A))$, then $\nu$ is a probability measure on $(\Bbb{R},\mathcal{B})$
Usually $\nu$ is called the distribution of $X$ and $\nu(-\infty,x]$ is called the cumulative distribution function of $X$.
And it is due to the change of variables formula that $E(X)=\int_{\Omega}g(X(\omega))\,d\mu(\omega)=\int_{\Bbb{R}}g(x)\,d\nu(x)$ for all $g$ bounded and measurable.
(See that for $g(x)=\mathbf{1}_{A}(x)$, you get $\nu(A)=\mu(X^{-1}(A))$ by definition.)
So now, how do you integrate wrt $\nu$? Well, here's where some assumptions regarding the absolute continuity of $\nu$ with $\text{Leb}$ (i.e the standard Lebesgue measure on $\Bbb{R}$) comes in
If there exists $f$ such that $\nu(A)=\int_{A}f(x)\,dx$ (dx refers to integral wrt the Lebesgue measure). Then we say $\nu$ is absolutely continuous wrt $\text{Leb}$ and we call $f(x)$ to be the Probability Density Function of $X$ (or $\nu$).
Thus $E(g(X))=\int_{\Omega}g(X(\omega))\,d\mu(\omega)=\int_{\Bbb{R}}g(x)f(x)\,dx$ . Ofcourse such an $f$ need not exist (not all continuous distributions have densities) but when they do, you have a nice expression.
If $\nu$ was absolutely continuous wrt the counting measure $\mu_{c}$ on a discrete set $D$, then we say $X$ has a discrete distribution. i.e. there exists a function $p(x)$ such that $\sum_{x\in D}p(x)=1$ and $\nu(A)=\int_{A}p(x)\,d\mu_{c}=\sum_{x\in A\cap D}p(x)$. This $p$ is called the pmf of $X$.
For all purposes, this function $p(x)$ equals $P(X=x)$ for all $x\in D$.
Then $E(g(X))=\int_{\Bbb{R}}g(x)\,d\nu(x)=\int_{D}g(x)p(x)\,d\mu_{c}=\sum_{x\in D}g(x)p(x)=\sum_{x\in D}g(x)P(X=x)$
Now, you see that it does not really matter what $\Omega,\mathcal{F},\mu$ are. What matters is the cdf $\nu(-\infty,x]$ which gives you everything about the Expectation of $X$ or functions of $X$. Or knowing about the density or pmf too provides all information.
In your example, a uniform random variable $U(-1,1)$ is any measurable function $X$ from some probability space $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},\mu)\to(\Bbb{R},\mathcal{B})$ such that $\mu(X^{-1}(-\infty,x])=\frac{x+1}{2}$ for all $x\in[-1,1]$ and equals $1$ for all $x\geq 1$ and is $0$ for $x\leq -1$. (i.e. this is the cdf).
Or equivalently, $\mu(X^{-1}(A))=\int_{A}\frac{\mathbf{1}_{[-1,1]}(x)}{2}\,dx$, i.e. the density wrt $\text{Leb}$ is $\frac{\mathbf{1}_{[-1,1]}(x)}{2}$.
That is why $E(e^{itX})=\frac{1}{2}\int_{-1}^{1}e^{itx}\,dx$.
If you want an example of a concrete function from a known probability space $\Omega,\mathcal{F},\mu$, then you can take $\Omega=[0,1],\mathcal{F}=\mathcal{B}$ and $\mu=\text{Leb}|_{[0,1]}$ and define a function $X$ such that
$X(\omega)=2\omega-1$ for $\omega\in[0,1]$ then $\mu(X^{-1}(\infty,x])=\frac{x+1}{2}$ and hence $X$ is a $U(-1,1)$ random variable.
If you wanted to create a $U(0,1)$ random variable, then take $X(\omega)=\omega$.
If you want a Bernoulli$(p)$ random variable, then define $X(\omega)=\mathbf{1}_{(0,p)}(\omega)$.
Play around some more and I'm sure you'll understand it.

The expected value only depends on the distribution of the random variable $X: \Omega \to \mathbb{R}$ not on the concrete probability space $(\Omega, \mathcal{F},\mu)$, in the sense that variables with the same distribution have the same expected value. The distribution is the pushforward measure $\mu^X$ on $(\mathbb{R},\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}))$. For a random variable $X: \Omega \to \mathbb{R}^d$ it is $X\sim \text{Unif}(A)$ for a Borel set $A \in \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}^d)$ if $d\mu^X = \frac{1}{\lambda^d(A)}1_{A}d\lambda^d$ (where $\lambda^d$ is the $d$-dimensional Lebesgue measure).
In the first example it is $d\mu^X = \frac{1}{\lambda((-1,1))}1_{(-1,1)}d\lambda = \frac{1}{2}1_{(-1,1)}d\lambda$ and thus
$$\mathbb{E}[e^{iX}] = \int_{\Omega}e^{iX}d\mu = \int_{\mathbb{R}}e^{ix}d\mu^X(x) = \int_{\mathbb{R}}e^{ix}\frac{1}{2}1_{(-1,1)}d\lambda(x) = \frac{1}{2}\int_{-1}^1e^{ix}dx = \sin(1).$$
In the second example it is $d\mu^Y = \frac{1}{\lambda(B(0,1))}1_{B(0,1)}d\lambda^2 = \frac{1}{\pi}1_{B(0,1)}d\lambda^2$ and thus
$$\mathbb{E}[\log{|Y|}] = \int_{\Omega}\log|Y|d\mu = \frac{1}{\pi}\int_{\mathbb{R}^2}\log|(x,y)|d\mu^Y(x,y) = \int_{\mathbb{R}^2}\log|(x,y)|\frac{1}{\pi}1_{B(0,1)}d\lambda^2(x,y) \\
= \frac{1}{\pi}\int_{B(0,1)}\log\sqrt{x^2+y^2}dxdy = \frac{1}{\pi}\int_{0}^{2\pi}\int_{0}^1 r\log r dr d\varphi \\
= 2\left(\left[\frac{1}{2}r^2 \log r\right]_0^1-\frac{1}{2}\int_0^1 r dr\right) = 2\left(0-\frac{1}{2}\cdot\frac{1}{2}\right) = -\frac{1}{2}$$

The pushforward measure is indeed enough for calculation of expectation of rv $X:\Omega\to\mathbb R$. But formally the expectation is defined as an integral wrt the underlying probability space hence false to state that it does not depend on it. See lotus.

@drhab Well, if two random variables have the same pushforward measure then the expectations are equal. In that sense the expectation is indeed independent of the concrete probability space of the variable. But of course one needs formally the probability space to define the expectation so it depends in that sense on the probability space. Still what really matters is the distribution.

I agree on that. We could connect the concept "expectation" directly with the concept "distribution".

Last remark: often though it is handsome to calculate expectations without paying any attention to the underlying distribution. Think e.g. of linearity of expectation.
